# Ember.js Namespace Issues

Tags: ember.js, javascript-namespaces

I have an Ember.js application I have been developing and which has been working great.  I am now attempting to integrate in a SIP over Websockets library called JsSIP.  Both my Ember app and a separate proof-of-concept SIP app work great independently; however, as soon as I integrate the two together I start seeing weird errors in the SIP library.  I finally narrowed things down to the fact that it's a namespace issue between the 2 APIs

I have seen at least one other SO question regarding namespace conflicts between Ember.js and other libraries which do any sort of DOM manipulation (such as JQuery Mobile).  To my knowledge, the SIP library I'm using is doing very little if any actual manipulation of the DOM. I have seen some suggestions for using RequireJS, although I really didn't want to have to modulize my client and don't even know if it would solve the namespace conflicts.  Would wrapping things in an Ember.Namespace help?

I've created a super simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfend/NV6pW/21/) which demonstrates the core issue.  Any suggestions on how I might go about solving this issue between the 2 libraries are greatly appreciated.  Here's the bare bones code which is included in the Fiddle:

```
// JsSIP code
try
{
    var configuration = {
      'uri':         "example@sip2sip.info",
      'password':    "password",
      'trace_sip':   true,
      'ws_servers':  "ws://example.com"
};
    myPhone = new JsSIP.UA(configuration);
    myPhone.start();
}
catch(e)
{
    console.log(e.message);
}

// Ember code
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of JsSIP.UA is transforming ws_servers into an array and iterating over it with `for(element in array)`, which trips in extensions to the Array prototype made by Ember.js. You can disable that with the following code for your SIP library to work out of the box (add it before including the Ember script):

```
window.Ember = {};
Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES = false;
```

This can have a big impact on your Ember app, though. Read this documentation page to learn more: http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/

Comment: thank you so much for the quick response!!!  This makes perfect sense.  I knew it was a conflict between the 2 libraries, was just having trouble narrowing down the exact issue.  Thanks again!! :)